# C++ circular reference, error when using methods, even after forward declaring

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, forward-declaration, circular-reference

Suppose I have:

```
class B;
class A{
    private:
        B *b;
    public:
        bar(){ b->foo()};
        foo();
}

class B{
    private:
        A *a;
    public:
        bar(){ a->foo();}
        foo();
}
```

When compiled this file gives an

> error "invalid use of incomplete type struct B",

even after I have forward declared the class B. As far as I understand it is because when I am calling the function `foo()` on `b`, the compiler still doesn't know that such a function exists. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 10):

The forward declaration provides no implementation details. `B` is not known to `A`, other than the fact that it exists.

To solve this, separate your declaration from the implementation.

You're also missing return types for the methods.

File A.h:

```
class B;
class A{
    private:
        B *b;
    public:
        void bar();
        void foo();
};
```

File A.cpp:

```
#include "A.h"
#include "B.h"
void A::bar(){ 
   b->foo();
}
```

File B.h:

```
class A;
class B{
    private:
        A *a;
    public:
        void bar();
        void foo();
};
```

File B.cpp:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"
void B::bar(){ 
   a->foo();
}
```

Comment: Note that you don't have to move the function definitions to source files. If you want to keep them inline, then place them in the header file *after* both class definitions, with an `inline` qualification.

Comment: @MikeSeymour The inline qualification is only a compiler hint. Even placing functions in header files or even in the class definition doesn't force the compiler to inline them. Moreover, compilers **can** inline functions defined in source files.

Comment: It may only be a "hint", but just about any compiler will inline a very small function like this if it can, as doing so will improve both speed and code size. Some compilers can inline functions between translation units, but many can't - if you care about performance and portability, then it's a good idea to define simple functions inline in header files when you can.

Comment: Inlining does improve speed, but I don't see how it can possibly improve code size... You should leave optimizations to the compiler.

Comment: It can improve code size by not generating the code necessary for a function call, and (if possible) not generating the inlined functions themselves. I agree that you should (usually) leave optimisations to the compiler; I do not agree with your suggestion here that you should deliberately *prevent* some compilers from optimising, unless there is a particular reason to prefer non-inline definitions.

Comment: I'm not suggesting preventing compiler optimization. Without benchmarking you can't even tell the code will behave better with or without inlining. I doubt that that could be a bottleneck. I prefer having readable code (i.e. keep implementation details separate) over one less jmp or call instruction in generated code, but that's just me.

Comment: And I prefer giving the compiler its best shot at optimising, as long as that doesn't significantly impact readability, but that's just me. Anyway, it's really not worth arguing about it: my point was just that there is an option to keep the functions inline if you want to, not that one shouldn't do as you suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Put the implementation in a source file instead of in the header.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because you try to use a method from `B` in `A::bar`. While class `B` has been *declared*, it has not been *defined*.

Like the others say, you should separate the definition and the implementation, and it will work.